# How to display different color pins in map in Android?

Tags: java, android, android-maps

I have displayed multiple pins in map in same color but i need to display different color pins for each location, Here is the code,

```
Drawable drawable;
AddItemizesOverlay itemizedOvrealy;
drawable = this.getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.color1);
        itemizedOverlay = new AddItemizedOverlay(drawable, mapView);
        for(int i=0;i<paramLat.size();i++)
        {
            lat = Double.parseDouble(paramLat.get(i)); 
            lon = Double.parseDouble(paramLong.get(i));
            geoPoint = new GeoPoint((int)(lat * 1E6), (int)(lon *1E6));
            geopoints.add(geoPoint);
            List<Overlay> mapOverlays = mapView.getOverlays();
            name = calloutName.get(i);
            overlayitem[i] = new Overlay
            Item(geoPoint, calloutName.get(i), "Time: " + calloutTime.get(i)); 
            itemizedOverlay.addOverlay(overlayitem[i]);
            mc.animateTo(geoPoint);
         }
            mapView.getOverlays().add(itemizedOverlay);
```

AddItemizedOverlay.java

```
 public AddItemizedOverlay(Drawable drawable, MapView mapView) {
         super(boundCenter(drawable), mapView);
         c = mapView.getContext();
     }
```

Here passed the pin image as drawable name as 'color1', but i need to send different colors pin as drawable. and in result each location marked by different pins.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to your code, `itemizedOverlay = new AddItemizedOverlay(drawable, mapView);` here you make any condition and change the drawable for each `paramLat`. So replace your `itemizedOverlay` inside for loop and set different drawable with if condition.

Comment: Hi, try this code within for loop at last 
 mapView.getOverlays().add(itemizedOverlay);

Comment: drawable = this.getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.marker);  can we store image file name as string and use that for get resource id as drawable?

Answer (score 2):

Create AddItemizesOverlay object in for loop and pass different different image for push pin .

```
GeoPoint point = new GeoPoint(lat.intValue(), lng.intValue());

drawable = this.getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.marker);
itemizedOverlay = new MyItemizedOverlay(drawable);
OverlayItem overlayItem = new OverlayItem(point, "", "");
itemizedOverlay.addOverlay(overlayItem);
mapOverlays.add(itemizedOverlay);


GeoPoint point2 = new GeoPoint(lt2.intValue(),long2.intValue() );
// All "B"s
drawable = this.getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.icon);
itemizedOverlay = new MyItemizedOverlay(drawable);
OverlayItem overlayItem1 = new OverlayItem(point2, "", "");
itemizedOverlay.addOverlay(overlayItem1);
mapOverlays.add(itemizedOverlay);
```

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to add multiple `ItemizedOverlay` to have different markers, as you can assign a different marker to each `OverlayItem` added to a single `ItemizedOverlay`.

Bellow an example on how to do it.

You create and define the bounds for each marker (pin1, pin2) using:

```
    pin1 = this.getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.pin_gps);
    pin1.setBounds((int)(-drawable_gps_pin.getIntrinsicWidth()/2),-drawable_gps_pin.getIntrinsicHeight(), (int)(drawable_gps_pin.getIntrinsicWidth()/2), 0); 
    pin2 = this.getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.pin_gps);
    pin2.setBounds((int)(-drawable_gps_pin.getIntrinsicWidth()/2),-
```

Then you create your `ItemizedOverlay` using as default one of trhe pins:

```
    itemizedOverlay = new AddItemizedOverlay(pin1, mapView);
```

When you want to add a marker that uses `pin1`:

```
    overlayitem = new OverlayItem(geoPoint, calloutName.get(i), "Time: " + calloutTime.get(i)); 
    itemizedOverlay.addOverlay(overlayitem);
```

When you want to add a marker that uses `pin2`:

```
    overlayitem = new OverlayItem(geoPoint, calloutName.get(i), "Time: " + calloutTime.get(i));
    overlayitem.setMarker(pin2);
    itemizedOverlay.addOverlay(overlayitem);
```

Finally you add the `ItemizedOverlay` to ´MapView`:

```
    mapView.getOverlays().add(itemizedOverlay);
```

Regards